# Single sign-on solutions for ExpressionEngine in enterprise using LDAP / Active Directory

Tags: ee2, authentication, single-sign-on

Can a single sign-on solution be used to share credentials between ExpressionEngine and LDAP/Active Directory?

Comment: We'll need a specific answerable question (or closely-related group of questions) for this to be considered on-topic. As it stands, you're soliciting opinions and discussion. Can you revise?

Comment: Sorry. Noob here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This LDAP extension looks like a good place to start](https://github.com/designbyfront/LDAP-Authentication-for-ExpressionEngine) - the extension is older, but it looks like all the pieces are in place. You could build on this as needed.

Comment: I have implimented this extension and it works well with a few tweaks. If you need any help of have questions, just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively easy to roll your own SSO solution because signing a user into ExpressionEngine is fairly simple.

If you have the appropriate data, it's easy to create an ExpressionEngine user, create a relationship (I've typically done this using a new database table) and sign this user in based on the response from the API you're using.

I'm not familiar with the required effort when it comes to working with LDAP but if you dig into the ExpressionEngine member module source code you'll see how simple it is to sign a user in or instantiate a new user.

Comment: I'm not a seasoned PHP developer, but may be able to get a feel for what's going on under the hood there. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. If you wanted to get really raw with it, it can be as simple as copy/pasting certain blocks of code. It's veeeeery simple to replicate.